# Custom locale strings for strftime in GCC

Tags: c, internationalization, stm32

I am writing the firmware for a clock which will run on an stm32f103 microcontroller. I am using gcc with the standard C libraries, and I'm formatting the clock display using the strftime function like this:

```
char sz[24];
strftime(sz, sizeof(sz), "%H:%M %p", &clockValues); // %H = 12 hour, %I = 24 hour, %p = AM/PM
```

As expected this gives an output like this:

```
12:45 PM
```

However due to the small size of the TFT display I'm using I want to replace the AM/PM with a single character which will show as a custom glyph (basically, AM or PM compressed into a single character space).

I assumed this would be a simple matter of creating a custom locale based on the C locale, but with the time format strings changed. I have searched but I haven't found a way to create custom locales.

Is it possible to change the template strings for locales in C?

Comment: Note: Comment `%I = 24 hour` seems extraneous in code.

Comment: How about post processing `sz` and remove last letter?

Comment: @chux - that's just a note to myself. Yes, post processing is always an option. If possible I would prefer to do it using template strings.

Comment: Your comment says `// %H = 12 hour, %I = 24 hour,` — your comment has the meaning of `%H` and `%I` reversed.  Use `%H` for 24-hour clock; use `%I` for 12-hour clock.

Comment: Creating, installing, using custom locales with custom code points in custom fonts is an entirely non-trivial and inherently platform-specific exercise.  It is not something that can be achieved easily.  Will you be making use of a PUA (private use area) in a Unicode font, or how will you introduce those characters?  What other characters are you going to inherit from where?  How are you going to handle font scaling?  Are you sure this is the way to go?

Comment: The font is no problem. I'm rendering my own ascii bitmap font, I can easily change a couple of unused characters into symbols. I just need strftime to output those characters for me.

Comment: @Jonathan: Noted that %H and %I have meaning reversed.